# OpenAI ChatGPT (GPT-3.5) API: Why am I not getting a response if the stream parameter is set to false?

Tags: php, openai-api, chatgpt-api

You can see the `$prompt` value in my application below. When I type this promp value, chatGPT does not give results. But this is because `"stream" => false` in the params. If `"stream" => true`, chatGPT gives results.

My question here is why chatGPT does not give results when `"stream" => false`. And what to do for it to give results.

```
$API_KEY = "API_KEY_HERE";

$model = 'gpt-3.5-turbo';
$header = [
    "Authorization: Bearer " . $API_KEY,
    "Content-type: application/json",
];

$temperature = 0.6;
$frequency_penalty = 0;
$presence_penalty= 0;
$prompt = 'What can you help me with? For example: What do you suggest to keep me motivated?';
 

$messages = array(
    array(
        "role" => "system",
        "content" => "Your name is 'JOHN DOE'. I want you to act as a motivational coach. I will provide you with some information about someone's goals and challenges, and it will be your job to come up with strategies that can help this person achieve their goals. This could involve providing positive affirmations, giving helpful advice or suggesting activities they can do to reach their end goal. if you don't understand the question, don't think too much, tell the user to be more specific with more details"
        ),
    array(
        "role" => "assistant",
        "content" => "Hello, I'm JOHN DOE, and I'm a motivational coach who loves helping people find their drive and achieve their goals. With years of experience in coaching and personal development, I've developed a unique approach to motivation that combines mindset, energy, and action."
    ),
    array(
        "role" => "user",
        "content" => $prompt
    )
);
//Turbo model
$isTurbo = true;
$url = "https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions";
$params = json_encode([
    "messages" => $messages,
    "model" => $model,
    "temperature" => $temperature,
    "max_tokens" => 1024,
    "frequency_penalty" => $frequency_penalty,
    "presence_penalty" => $presence_penalty,
    "stream" => false
]);

$curl = curl_init($url);
$options = [
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $header,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $params,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
    CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION => function($curl, $data) {
        //echo $curl;
        $httpCode = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

        if ($httpCode != 200) {
            $r = json_decode($data);
            echo 'data: {"error": "[ERROR]","message":"'.$r->error->message.'"}' . PHP_EOL;
        } else {
            $trimmed_data = trim($data); 
            if ($trimmed_data != '') {
                $response_array = json_decode($trimmed_data, true);
                $content = $response_array['choices'][0]['message']['content'];
                echo $content;
                ob_flush();
                flush();
            }
        }
        return strlen($data);
    },
];

curl_setopt_array($curl, $options);
$response = curl_exec($curl);

if ($response === false) {
    echo 'data: {"error": "[ERROR]","message":"'.curl_error($curl).'"}' . PHP_EOL;
}else{

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you don't get a response back if you set `"stream" => false` is that the whole code is designed to return a response in a streaming fashion when the `stream` parameter is set to `true`.

With the following modification, the response will be processed as a whole, regardless of the value of the `stream` parameter.

Try this:

```
$API_KEY = "API_KEY_HERE";

$model = 'gpt-3.5-turbo';
$header = [
    "Authorization: Bearer " . $API_KEY,
    "Content-type: application/json",
];

$temperature = 0.6;
$frequency_penalty = 0;
$presence_penalty= 0;
$prompt = 'What can you help me with? For example: What do you suggest to keep me motivated?';

$messages = array(
    array(
        "role" => "system",
        "content" => "Your name is 'JOHN DOE'. I want you to act as a motivational coach. I will provide you with some information about someone's goals and challenges, and it will be your job to come up with strategies that can help this person achieve their goals. This could involve providing positive affirmations, giving helpful advice or suggesting activities they can do to reach their end goal. if you don't understand the question, don't think too much, tell the user to be more specific with more details"
        ),
    array(
        "role" => "assistant",
        "content" => "Hello, I'm JOHN DOE, and I'm a motivational coach who loves helping people find their drive and achieve their goals. With years of experience in coaching and personal development, I've developed a unique approach to motivation that combines mindset, energy, and action."
    ),
    array(
        "role" => "user",
        "content" => $prompt
    )
);

$url = "https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions";

$params = json_encode([
    "messages" => $messages,
    "model" => $model,
    "temperature" => $temperature,
    "max_tokens" => 1024,
    "frequency_penalty" => $frequency_penalty,
    "presence_penalty" => $presence_penalty,
    "stream" => false
]);

$curl = curl_init($url);
$options = [
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $header,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $params,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
];

curl_setopt_array($curl, $options);
$response = curl_exec($curl);

if ($response === false) {
    echo 'data: {"error": "[ERROR]","message":"'.curl_error($curl).'"}' . PHP_EOL;
}else{
    $response_array = json_decode($response, true);
    $content = $response_array['choices'][0]['message']['content'];
    echo $content;
}
```

Comment: As far as I understand, if we run it with "stream" => false, then it doesn't go to the next line and writes the whole answer in one line. For example 1. first item 2. second item 3. third item. Do I need "stream" => true here to sort the 1st, 2nd and 3rd items one after the other.

Comment: Streaming is all about *how* you want to get a response. Let's say you get a long response from the OpenAI API. If you set `stream` to `true`, you will get the completion back word-after-word (like ChatGPT does). If you set `stream` to `false`, you will get the whole completion back at once. Streaming is meant to be used when you expect a long response or when the OpenAI API is overloaded and very slow. In this case, it's a far better user experience to get a word-after-word response than to wait very long time for the whole response.